# Import CSV into mongodb using node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I want to import CSV file data into MongoDB using node.js. Here column names are not constant. Can we create a schema based on the CSV header? I will remove the old data on each import and create schema and data for the new import.

Comment: So ... "remove the old data" sounds like every time you do this load, you will drop the collection first, then crack the header for field names, and then insert lines 1-n using those fields?

Comment: Yes @BuzzMoschetti

Comment: The best you can do reliably is import the cracked columns as strings.  There is no type information in the CSV header.   Beyond this, it is more of a javascript file reading and cracking exercise more than mongodb.